# Reduce space complexity opportunities (Dynamic programming problem)

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming, space-complexity

This post is related to find opportunities in improving the space complexity of a DP (dynamic programming) classic problem entitled **howSum**.

### Context

**Problem Description**: `howSum(target, vec[])` is a function that should return an array containing any combination of elements that add up to the target parameter. You can return any combination, and reuse elements from the `vec` array. If there is no combination available, return `null`.

**Achievements**: I have implemented this problem both recursively, and using the DP tabulation method.

##### Recursive Method

**Time Complexity** - using caching: `O(n*m*m)`, where

> m = height of the recursive tree
>
> n = length of the `vec` array, that will branch my tree *n at each level in worst case
>
> the additional *m comes from copying (you'll see the line highlighted in the code below)

**Space Complexity** - using caching: `O(n*m^2)`

```
using Cache = std::map<int64_t, std::optional<std::vector<int64_t>>>;
using OptionalVector = std::optional<std::vector<int64_t>>;

OptionalVector howSum(int64_t target, const std::vector<int64_t>& vec)
{
    static Cache cache;

    auto found = cache.find(target);
    if(found != std::end(cache)) return cache[target];

    if(target == 0) return std::vector<int64_t>();
    if(target < 0) return std::nullopt;

    for(const auto& x : vec)
    {
        int64_t remainder = target - x;
        OptionalVector remainderResult = howSum(remainder, vec);

        if(remainderResult != std::nullopt)
        {
            remainderResult->push_back(x);
            cache[target] = remainderResult; // <---- copy
            return cache[target];
        }
    }

    cache[target] = std::nullopt;
    return std::nullopt;
}
```

##### Tabulation Method

**Time Complexity** `O(n*m*m^2)`, where

> m = size of the table rows
>
> n = length of the `vec` array
>
> the additional *m^2 comes from copying (you'll see the line highlighted in the code below)

**Space Complexity**: `O(n*m*m^2)`

```
std::optional<std::vector<uint64_t>> howSumTabulation(uint64_t target, const std::vector<uint64_t>& vec)
{
    std::vector<std::optional<std::vector<uint64_t>>> table;
    uint32_t lengthRows = target + 1;
    table.resize(lengthRows); // created space

    // Create an empty array for the first column
    table[0].emplace();

    int counter = 0;

    for(auto& row : table)
    {
        if(row != std::nullopt)
        {
            for(const auto& x : vec)
                if( x + counter < lengthRows )
                {
                    std::vector<uint64_t> currentColumn = *row; // <---- 1st copy
                    currentColumn.push_back(x);
                    table[x+counter] = currentColumn; // <---- 2nd copy
                }
        }
        counter ++;
    }

    return table[target];
}
```

Is there a way I could improve my space complexity using `std::move` or maybe other data structures for this particular algorithm?

Comment: ot: `std::optional<std::vector<int64_t>>` is a bit of overkill. Vectors can be empty, ie they already do optionally have elements or not

Comment: I know but in this problem, an empty vector has a different meaning from a null vector.